# Corrupted MathJax

Tags: bug, mathjax

Is anyone else seeing this issue? It started about two days ago. MathJax gets totally corrupted. If you refresh the page (sometimes several times), it corrects the output.

Here is an example on a [*question*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612949/inverse-laplace-transformation-simple-question) I just answered, but it happens quite randomly. I am using Chrome.

[image]

Comment: ZALGO. HE COMES...

Comment: It happens to me on the iPad occasionally. A crude estimate is 2.39 % of the time.

Comment: Yes, it happens sometimes (osx, chrome)

Comment: I am 97.61% sure this is another conflict between Winterbash script and MathJaX. Try taking the anti-hat stance. (I did it on the first day, not because I'm actually anti-hat, but because I'm anti-buggy-javascript.)

Comment: I have been anti-hat since day 1!

Comment: @PostNoBills I see what you did there...

Comment: @anorton: the odds are $40.841:1$ that you did :-)

Comment: It would help to know more about your system. In particular, Chrome and OS version for a start, then also any addons or user scripts that modify the page (try to deactivate those for a test). It would be helpful if there's a specific page where this happens more often, also whether it can go bad again after being ok once (would rule out download issues). Perhaps a particular type of content is common (like a specific environment). Anything that might narrow it down.

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1. Browser: Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m. I suspect this has a correlation to the hats.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had missed the winter bash references in the earlier comments. Yes, that's probably the source. Not sure we can do much about it but if there's a lot of interest, we can sit down with SE folks to sort it out.